# Testing: Which country doesn't support billing library?

Tags: android, testing, android-billing, in-app-subscription

Our app support in app subscription.
Actually we didn't check this method before trying in-app-subscritpion process:

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference#isBillingSupported

This missing check, I suspect it can cause a crash in our app.

In order to verify the behavior before making a patch, I need to change the google account (The one I'm using to test the purchase) with one of the country where google play doesn't support billing.

Where can I find the list of unsupported country?
Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of supported countries
https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/143779